# How to tail multiple files from different terminals in a single output

Tags: unix, terminal, grep, tail

I want to monitor logs in a single window , we are using load-balancing as part-of this
request can come to any one of the machines , we have 4 machines. 

**Wanted to tail all four logs with a single command and in a single window, out put file.**

user@terminal1 /logs/somelog.log , user@terminal2 /logs/somelog.log, 

user@terminal3 /logs/somelog.log , user@terminal4 /logs/somelog.log

As we cannot install any tool in unix servers they are not in our full-control, please suggest 
generic command. 
**OR** 
any tool or EXE throw which we can tail in windows 7.

This will be useful for support Teams.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable remote logging on all the servers and choose one of them as the repository for the remote logs, using SYSLOG or SYSLOG-NG its is already installed With UNIX/LINUX based system, but firstwhat unix machine you have because the configuration could be slightly different

Comment: We are using Linux version 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64 version, but we cannot do any changes or request only we can spool the logs.

Comment: we are allowed to only use tail command on the servers to check the logs. (spooling --> checking logs)

Answer (score 0):

tail -f FILE_1 FILE_2 ... FILE_N